# FilamentPHP: Uploaded file not saving to database and create button keeps loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, filamentphp

I'm currently working on a project using FilamentPHP for file uploads to an S3 bucket. I have set up a file upload field for image with various configurations like rules, disk, directory, etc. However, when I try to create a record with the uploaded file, it doesn't save to the database, and the create button keeps loading indefinitely.

Here's a code I'm using for the file upload:

```
FileUpload::make('image')
    ->rules(['image', 'max:1024'])
    ->nullable()
    ->image()
    ->imageEditor()
    ->placeholder('Image')
    ->disk('s3')
    ->directory('photos')
    ->visibility('private')
    ->columnSpan([
        'default' => 12,
        'md' => 12,
        'lg' => 12,
    ]),
```

I've checked my FilamentPHP component methods, form submission, validation errors, and database insertion logic, but I can't seem to find the issue.

Here are some additional details:

The file does get uploaded to the S3 bucket in livewire-temp, but it's not being saved to the database.
There are no error messages displayed, and I've checked the logs for any exceptions, but there's nothing relevant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked column name and fillable prop in model

Comment: And pls check the network tab for any errors